# Count amount of disk space needed by files bigger than x

Tags: unix, shell, file-management

In Linux, I know I can use

```
find ./ -size +1M
```

to find files which are bigger than 1M, but how do I sum the total space needed by these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `-exec`ute a program on each of the `find` results.

> `-exec utility [argument ...] {} +`
>
> Same as `-exec`, except that ```{}''`is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for each invocation of utility.  This behaviour is similar to that of`xargs(1)`.

Run `du -c` to sum of disk usage (number of used blocks) on the results, like this:

```
find ./ -size +1M -exec du -c {} +
```

Optionally add `-h` to get human readable sizes, or `-k` for 1k blocks. Add `-s` if a different `find` expression also returns folders.

This requires that there aren't *too many* results, since it builds a single `du` call from the file names, and if that gets too long, it'll split it up into separate calls with separate totals.